# How to show that the t-distribution density function is a pdf?

Tags: distributions, density-function, t-distribution

We know that the pdf of the t-distribution is :
$$f(t|p)=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{p+1}{2})}{p^{\frac{1}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{p}{2})}\cdot\frac{1}{(1+\frac{t^2}{p})^{\frac{p+1}{2}}} \;\;\;\; \forall t\in\mathbb{R}$$
$$\equiv \frac{1}{p^{\frac{1}{2}}B(\frac{p}{2},\frac{1}{2})}\cdot\frac{1}{(1+\frac{t^2}{p})^{\frac{p+1}{2}}}$$
where $B(\cdot)$ is the beta function. What I wish to do is show that 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\cdot\frac{1}{(1+\frac{t^2}{p})^{\frac{p+1}{2}}}dt=p^{\frac{1}{2}}B(\frac{p}{2},\frac{1}{2})$$
so I can ultimately show that the integral over $\mathbb{R}$ of the t-distribution is equal to $1$. However, I have been unsuccessful at the various points that I've attempted to show this. Typically, this is what I attempt:

> Let $u=\frac{t}{\sqrt p}$. Then $du=\frac{1}{\sqrt p} dt \implies \sqrt p\cdot du=dt$ and we end up with
>   $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\cdot\frac{1}{(1+\frac{t^2}{p})^{\frac{p+1}{2}}}dt=\sqrt p \int_{\mathbb{R}}\cdot\frac{1}{(1+u^2)^{\frac{p+1}{2}}}du$$

I have no idea how to get the last integral to be my desired Beta function. The next substitution I attempt gets me close, but yet still so far:

> Now let $v=1+u^2\implies u=\sqrt{v-1}$. Then $dv=2u\cdot du \implies \frac{1}{2}dv=u\cdot du$ and we have
>   $$\sqrt p \int_{\mathbb{R}}\cdot\frac{1}{(1+u^2)^{\frac{p+1}{2}}}du=\sqrt p \int_{\mathbb{R}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{v-1}(v)^{\frac{p+1}{2}}}dv=\sqrt p \int_{\mathbb{R}} (v-1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot v^{-\frac{p+1}{2}}dv$$

Does anyone know how to proceed from this step, or is there another route one recommends?

Comment: The "pdf of the t-distribution" is *not* equal to 1. For the pdf to be constant (and equal to 1), it couldn't be $t$. You mean something other than what you said in your first sentence.

Comment: One easier way is to start from the definition of the $t$ random variable, namely a ratio of a normal variable by a normalised $\chi_t^2$ variable.

Comment: @ Gleb_b I've edited the post to make clear what it is I was trying to accomplish. Thank you for your statement.

@ Xi'an I will try this out and the morning and let you know how this goes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Substitute $t^2/p = x$, $tdt =(\sqrt{p}/2) x^{-1/2}dx$, to produce

$$\int_\mathbb{R} \left(1 + t^2/p\right)^{-(p+1)/2} dt = 2\int_0^\infty \left(1 + t^2/p\right)^{-(p+1)/2} dt=\sqrt{p}\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{x^{1/2-1}}{\left(1 + x\right)^{1/2 + p/2}}dx.$$

[The integral on the right hand is a standard formulation of](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties) $B(p/2, 1/2)$, *QED*.

If, like me, you are familiar with a different integral representation of Beta (used for the Beta distribution), then note that the substitution $x = y/(1-y)$, $dx = dy/(1-y)^2$ entails $1+x = 1/(1-y)$, thereby converting this integral into

$$\int_0^1 y^{\alpha-1}(1-y)^{\beta-1}dy = \text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$$

with $\alpha=1/2, \beta=p/2$.  The symmetry $\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta) = \text{Beta}(\beta,\alpha)$ completes the demonstration.

Comment: Another nice proof is found here:  http://www.randomservices.org/random/special/Student.html

Comment: @Stats Thank you for the reference.  That's related to a standard way of showing that $B(\alpha,\beta)=\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)/\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)$.

Comment: Oh whoa! Thank you very much, whuber! The x=y(1-y) substitution was exactly what I needed. Though, it's very helpful to know of the other representations of the beta function, as I'd grown so accustomed to the $y^{a-1}(1-y)^{b-1}$ form.